# Laravel check validation parameter only if not registered user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have a form, which displays a Google reCaptcha if no user logged in. If there's a user logged in, no reCaptcha is shown.

OK.

But When I validate those POST parameters I need to check if the user is logged in or not, to validate reCaptcha or not. Like this:

```
//Check if logged in user
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $request->validate([
                'category' => 'bail|required|numeric',
                'title' => 'bail|required|max:160|banned_words',
                'price' => 'numeric',
                'description' => 'bail|required|banned_words',
                'contact_name' => 'bail|required|max:100',
                'contact_email' => 'bail|required|email|max:140',
                'phone' => 'bail|required|max:20',
                'ad_region' => 'bail|required|numeric',
                "agree" => 'bail|required',
            ]);
        } else {
            $request->validate([
                'category' => 'bail|required|numeric',
                'title' => 'bail|required|max:160|banned_words',
                'price' => 'numeric',
                'description' => 'bail|required|banned_words',
                'contact_name' => 'bail|required|max:100',
                'contact_email' => 'bail|required|email|max:140',
                'phone' => 'bail|required|max:20',
                'ad_region' => 'bail|required|numeric',
                "agree" => 'bail|required',
                'g-recaptcha-response' => 'recaptcha',              //Recaptcha Google Check
            ]);
        }
```

So, is there a more pretty inline solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$request->validate([
    'category' => 'bail|required|numeric',
    'title' => 'bail|required|max:160|banned_words',
    'price' => 'numeric',
    'description' => 'bail|required|banned_words',
    'contact_name' => 'bail|required|max:100',
    'contact_email' => 'bail|required|email|max:140',
    'phone' => 'bail|required|max:20',
    'ad_region' => 'bail|required|numeric',
    "agree" => 'bail|required',
    'g-recaptcha-response' => Auth::check() ? '' : 'recaptcha',
]);
```

Laravel itself uses an empty string to skip validation rule, e.g. [check this code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/3c6febb810af2128c479b402c36859d7572665cc/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/RequiredIf.php#L36).

Comment: Nope, array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given 

Comment: Yeah, this worked now. I like more the ternary operation solution thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create the list first. Then append the recaptcha if user is logged in:

```
$fields = [
                'category' => 'bail|required|numeric',
                'title' => 'bail|required|max:160|banned_words',
                'price' => 'numeric',
                'description' => 'bail|required|banned_words',
                'contact_name' => 'bail|required|max:100',
                'contact_email' => 'bail|required|email|max:140',
                'phone' => 'bail|required|max:20',
                'ad_region' => 'bail|required|numeric',
                "agree" => 'bail|required',
            ];
//Check if this is a guest user
if (!Auth::check()) {
   $fields['g-recaptcha-response'] = 'recaptcha';
}

$request->validate($fields);
```

Comment: Yes, but a bit fix:

if (!Auth::check())